# Visual Studio Installer: how to install the program into Program files using msi?

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I'm trying to create the installation for my program. If I run msi it always install the exe and dlls into the root intstead of Program files. If I run exe it works good but I need to have msi besides what I don't want. How to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using InstallShield LE by chance?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use it because I have only limited edition for VS where it works improperly on VS (it's 64 bit version).

Answer (score 0):

seems like properties aren't being set correctly.
What technology are you using to create your installer ?